# ffmpeg unrecognized file type

Tags: macos, ffmpeg

I'm using Mac OS and ffmpeg.  I'm attempting to convert mp3 to mp4 with image background and overlay audio visualization.
The below works when converting mp3 to mp4 with image:

```
$mp3 = "/Users/vanessa/Downloads/test/Marco.mp3";
    $image = "/Users/vanessa/Downloads/test/maxresdefault.jpg";
    $video = "/Users/vanessa/Downloads/test/videos/test2.mp4";

  exec("/usr/local/Cellar/ffmpeg/4.1_3/bin/ffmpeg -loop 1 -i $image -i $mp3 -c:v libx264 -c:a aac -strict experimental -b:a 192k -shortest $video 2>&1",$output);
```

I can successfully play test2.mp4.  When i attempt to do add an overlay of audio visualization.  I can see in get info how it looks in the preview section but when i click on the file it says : **File open error:Unrecognized file type**

```
exec("/usr/local/Cellar/ffmpeg/4.1_3/bin/ffmpeg -y -i $mp3 -loop 1 -i $image -filter_complex '[0:a]showwaves=s=1280x175:colors=White:mode=line,format=yuv420p[v];[1:v][v]overlay=0:200[outv]' -map '[outv]' -pix_fmt yuv420p -map 0:a -c:v libx264 -c:a copy -shortest $video 2>&1",$output);
```

Where did i go wrong? The player i'm using is Quicktime.

Comment: Some players don't like MP3 in MP4, but I am unable to test QuickTime. Try changing `-c:a copy` to `-c:a aac` (and no need for `-strict experimental`). If it still fails include your command (preferably unscripted), and the complete log.